# How do I parse application/vnd.surveymonkey.response.v1+json?

Tags: 7, services

I recently asked a question about setting up SurveyMonkey webhooks here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252571/surveymonkey-v3-webhook-callback

After laborious troubleshooting, I've determined that the issue is that I need to be able to parse the request as application/vnd.surveymonkey.response.v1+json.

How do I do that?

There's no option to add this type of parser, or a custom parser, in the REST server config. Googling for a few hours has come up with nothing. In a Drupal REST endpoint, how can I use this parser type?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct protocol is - if I should close my other question, please let me know and I would be glad to do so. I would also appreciate it if someone could add a SurveyMonkey tag.

Comment: I don’t think we need a tag for that particular service, but we could instead make this question much more generic and provide extra value that way. It could essentially be “how do I assign a particular parser to a non-standard content type through the rest module?”, with SurveyMonkey mentioned as an example

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to use [hook_rest_server_request_parsers_alter()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21services%21servers%21rest_server%21rest_server.api.php/function/hook_rest_server_request_parsers_alter/7). This way, the `application/vnd.surveymonkey.response.v1` Content-Type can be mapped to the standard JSON parser.

```
function MY_MODULE_rest_server_request_parsers_alter(&$parsers) {
  $parsers['application/vnd.surveymonkey.response.v1+json'] =  'ServicesParserJSON';
}
```